# run android task getting error in VSTS task group while building pipeline

Tags: android, react-native, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to create a pipeline for react native mobile application. I have created task group with npm custom task and the command is run android.

[image]

While running pipeline in this task is failing continuously. As per the error message:

```
Execution failed for task  com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

Where is the issue? or what is the command to build android apk in react application?

Comment: Can you build the app successfully on your local dev machine? According the error message, seems you need to connect a real phone device or start the emulator.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT its working in local.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an Android device to run your React Native Android app. This can be either a physical Android device, or more commonly an [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator.html).

> what is the command to build android apk in react application?

To build android project we can use Gradle, it's a common build tool used for building Android projects. See the [Gradle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops) task for more information.

You can reference the following articles to build the android apk:

- [Build, test, and deploy Android apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/android?view=azure-devops)
- [Using Azure DevOps to create a CI/CD pipeline for an Android application built with React Native](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/using-azure-devops-to-create-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-an-android/ba-p/1094422)

Comment: Is this gradle task produce a apk file ?

Comment: @sahal Yes, the gradle task will build the APK. Please refer to the reference links mentioned in above answer, it's straightforward to follow. Just have a try for that.

Comment: @Sahal Have you tried the steps mentioned in the links, is that working for you?